# problem with setting screen resolution for win 7 in virtual pc

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual-pc

I'm trying to run windows 7 on virtual pc. My host OS is windows XP. The vm is running fine but i could not set screen resolution in windows 7 to equal to host OS.

My windows XP is running on 1366*768
but
My windows 7 in virtual pc can only set to 1152*768 as a maximum resolution.

I'd like to know how to config virtual-pc to display the same resolution as host OS.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Coordinate full-screen video resolution with the host operating system.**

To coordinate full-screen video resolution with the host operating system

Open Virtual PC Console.

On the File menu, click Options.

Click Full-Screen Mode, and then select or clear the Adjust screen resolution so the host operating system is the same as the guest operating system check box.

*Refer VPC Help for more details.*

Comment: I've tried that folling VPC help but it does not work at all. It seems VGA card in windows 7 is standard VGA graphic adapter which allow me to set the maximum resolution to 1152*768.

Comment: My another VPC that is windows XP can set the screen resolution to the same with host OS but with windows 7..can not!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "Integration features" into Virtual OS (virtual pc window top: tools-> Enable Integration Features).